# Gradle 5: BOM dependencies are not written to pom file

Tags: gradle, maven-bom

I'm trying to use a BOM to build project A with Gradle 5. The pom file that's created does not correctly contain the BOM or the dependencies coming from it (see below). Moreover, Trying to build project B that depends on A fails on project A's pom.

When working with DependencyManagementPlugin (i.e. Not using Gradle 5 native support), everything works:

```
apply plugin:         
io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.DependencyManagementPlugin

dependencyManagement {
  imports {
    mavenBom 'myGroup:infra-bom:1.0.+'
  }
}
```

Creates this in project A's pom in a dependencyManagement block:

```
 <dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
       <artifactId>infra-bom</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.25</version>
       <scope>import</scope>
       <type>pom</type>
     </dependency>
   </dependencies>
 </dependencyManagement>
```

Trying to make it work with Gradle 5 isn't so lucky:

dependencies {

```
compile platform ('myGroup:infra-bom:1.0.+')
...
...
```

}

gradle dependencies shows correct versions from the BOM, but it creates this in project A's pom in the existing dependencies block:

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
   <artifactId>infra-bom</artifactId>
   <version>null</version>                   // note the null here
   <scope>compile</scope>
 </dependency>
```

Which fails builds trying to use it.

Am I correctly using Gradle 5 native support for BOM? What does it include?